# Eating scroll-wheel events on winforms Textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox, event-handling, scroll

I want to handle scroll-wheel events on a Winforms textbox if the Control key is down. Although of course I can, it still scrolls the underlying textbox, can I disable this somehow?

Comment: Well, thank you for down-voting and not telling me why mysterious stranger. Your input is much appreciated.

Comment: From the title on the downvote button, I'd say your question `does not show any research effort`, because it doesn't

Comment: I only post here as a last resort, precisely because SO has become rude and unhelpful over the past few years. I have googled it, I have disassembled the control in question using ILSpy to try and find a solution but everything came up negative. If you don't know the answer, just move on. If you do know the answer and its trivial, write it down.

Comment: Then why didn't you say you'd tried those things? I've always found SO helpful and professional. Perhaps you should rethink the way you use SO

Comment: So what should I say? "I already googled it, so you don't have to"? Unless I have something to show for my efforts it's just pointless information. It's a very simple, generic question that may or may not have an answer.

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because of how you phrased the question?  You'd normally refer to it as "capturing events" or "intercepting" rather than "eating".  Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163007/catch-textbox-scroll-event

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Write an Event that Happens when Mouse Scrolls in TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671754/how-can-i-write-an-event-that-happens-when-mouse-scrolls-in-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must override WndProc of textbox and ignore EN_VSCROLL message when Control is down.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I have to catch WM_MouseWheel (&H20A) but then I can then intercept the message. Of course then the MouseWheel event also no longer fires, but that's easy to get around. Thanks!