# Subscribe to a TextBox's scrollbar's scroll event

Tags: c#, winforms

`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` has a ScrollBars property that is only a `ScrollBars` enum, it doesn't actually link to instances of scrollbars, e.g., `VScrollBar`.  If I could access a `TextBox`s `VScrollBar`, I could subscribe to that object's `Scroll` event.

Is there a way to access scrollbar instances of `TextBox`s?  How can I subscribe to when the `TextBox` scrolls, without using P/Invoke if possible?

Comment: I know you said you wanted to avoid P/Invoke, but this seems fairly straight forward - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163007/catch-textbox-scroll-event

Comment: That does look fairly simple to use, Daniel.  I was just wondering if there was anything in the .NET API that supported this.  <rant>There *should* be.</rant>

Comment: @SamPearson winforms doesn't support too much stuff. If you don't feel like having to resort to such horrible hacks you'd rather be using current, relevant technology.

Comment: "Horrible hacks".  Hardly.  P/invoke is a perfectly legitimate way to leverage the Win32 API in managed applications.

Comment: @DonBoitnott right. since the winforms API is *incomplete* and *lacking*, you need to resort to lower level OS API calls for the simplest tasks (such as handling a `ScrollBar`'s scroll changed event). Really sounds like a hack to me. BTW, my point still stands, the OP should look into decent, usable technology instead ;)