# How can I catch scroll events in windows forms ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, reportviewer

I have reportViewer control on a form. I wan't to do something on form when reportViewer scrolled up or down:

```
this.reportViewer1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.reportViewer1_Scroll);

        private void reportViewer1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //call method
        }
```

But it's not working. How to fix it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163007/catch-textbox-scroll-event

Answer (score -1):

Scroll event do not appear to be accessible in the Control. The nearest I could get was Page Navigation events

Answer (score -1):

loviji:

It's a bug of .Net framework 4.x and it is reported to Microsoft Connect.

([ReportViewer control scroll event not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668317/reportviewer-control-scroll-event-not-fired))

ps:
I have post this [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ae9eb6a9-a708-4d0d-b612-158d78785cca/reportviewer-control-scroll-event-not-fired?forum=winforms#4d35acfd-f4e3-45f4-977e-aad11bd182fc) on msdn developer forum,
a Microsoft Contingent Staff(Bob) verified this issue and it is existence.
So I reported this [issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3112352) to Microsoft Connect.

And Microsoft Connect answers at 2016/12/07 22:29

"Yes, ReportViewer's scrollbars are not working now, it is a known bug for Winforms ScrollableControl. And we are investigating."