# ReportViewer control scroll event not fired

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, reportviewer

I am draging scrollbar of reportviewer control to try to fire the scroll event,
but it does not work.
DataGridView control shows the messagebox, source code like below.

```
private void reportViewer1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("reportviewer is scrolling!");
}

private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("datagridview is scrolling!");
}
```

Have anyone encounter this problem?

Thanks.

UI - Windows forms
Language - C#
OS - Windows 7 64bit
Tools - Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 + .Net Framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ae9eb6a9-a708-4d0d-b612-158d78785cca/reportviewer-control-scroll-event-not-fired?forum=winforms#4d35acfd-f4e3-45f4-977e-aad11bd182fc) of .Net framework 4.x
(Thank Bob for his help)

The bug is reported to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3112352)