# How can I Write an Event that Happens when Mouse Scrolls in TextBox?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, scroll, delegates

I wanna change the number of the TextBox when The Mouse Scrolls.
 I have a Scroll TextBox But I Don't wanna use that. Is There any Event related to this?
Should I write an TextBox Event? If yes, How can I write a textBox event that Happens when Mouse Scrolls?

Comment: Are you using winform??

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows Form Application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163007/catch-textbox-scroll-event

Comment: Actually I didn't Understand The code and I don't want to use API Functions. Is there Any Better Way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MouseWheel` event is there alright:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.MouseWheel += textBox1_MouseWheel;
}

void textBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But it is not visible in the event editor. No idea why..

You can find the full list of events through `Intellisense` like this:

Enter the Control's name and a dot. Now watch the dropdownlist for the event you need. When you have it write `+=` add press `Tab` twice. This hooks up the event and creates a stub for it.

Comment: Are you sure that the event arguments are correct, I never used this event but in the documentation they are using MouseWheelEventArgs.

Comment: Well they are as created by VS. The `MouseWheelEventArgs` are not from Winforms but from WPF. They contain a Delta alright, which has at least a sign that can be used, even if the value is always the same for my mice..

Comment: @TaW my bad sorry about that :)

Comment: I know this is an old question but inside the "textBox1_MouseWheel()" method, you are looking for e.delta to be positive (scroll wheel went up) or negative (scroll wheel when down).

Answer (score 1):

Use ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event in xaml. Here is an example to implement auto scroll log textbox. Scroll up stops the auto scroll action and scroll down resume action.

XAML:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="LogTextBox" Background="Black" Foreground="LightGray" TextChanged="OnTextChanged"
    IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="OnScroll">
</TextBox>
```

C#:

```cs
public partial class LogTextBlock : UserControl
{
    public LogTextBlock() => InitializeComponent();

    bool m_autoScroll = true;

    void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_autoScroll) LogTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }

    void OnScroll(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var verticalChange = e.VerticalChange;

        if (verticalChange > 0)
            m_autoScroll = true;
        else if (verticalChange < 0)
            m_autoScroll = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [MouseWheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Check the documentation.

Comment: TextBox Doesn't have MouseWheel Event. Could you Explain More?

Comment: @AmirPourmand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx. MSDN says that they have.

Comment: .Yes They Say but I TextBox Events. I can't see It. It has Been disappeared. :D

Answer (score -1):

VS studio is not `Intellisense` becuase some properties and methods are

`[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]`